# html title using basename(__DIR__) to output parent AND current folder name

Tags: php, html, title

I'm using this code to assign to the html  tag the current folder's name

```
 <title><?php echo basename(__DIR__); ?></title>
```

what if I also wanted to include the parent folder's name in the title, so that the title would look something like "parentfolder-currentfolder"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<?php echo basename(dirname(__DIR__))."-".basename(__DIR__); ?>
```

Comment: And what if the parent folder is null ?

Comment: that did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.realpath.php) to get where you want:

```
echo basename(realpath(__DIR__.'/../'));
```